# Revit Synchronization event

Tags: api, synchronization, revit

Starting with this...
https://github.com/jeremytammik/RevitLookup/blob/master/CS/EventTrack/Events/ApplicationEvents.cs

I'm trying to add an event listener for a synchronization event.  the code below throws an error stating that the m_app is null.  Can i not subscribe to this event while Revit is starting up?

I was able to do this before with `application.ViewActivated += ....`.  Im wondering if this has something to do with DB vs UI driven events and when they are allowed to be subscribed to?  I just don't know.

```
  namespace RevitModelHealth
{
    public class checkHealth : IExternalApplication
    {
        // Document doc;
        static public Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.Application m_app = null;

        public Result OnShutdown(UIControlledApplication application)
        {
            return Result.Succeeded;
        }

        public Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication application)
        {

            m_app.DocumentSynchronizingWithCentral += new EventHandler<DocumentSynchronizingWithCentralEventArgs>(m_app_DocumentSavingToCentral);
            return Result.Succeeded;
        }

        void m_app_DocumentSavingToCentral(object sender, Autodesk.Revit.DB.Events.DocumentSynchronizingWithCentralEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("asd","asd");
        }

    }
}
```

Here is updated code reflecting my response to the first answer.  The message box opens when the document is loaded.  No errors are thrown when I try to initialize the synchronization event handlers, however, neither of the message boxes open before or after a synchronization event.

```
  public class checkHealth : IExternalApplication
    {
        // Document doc;
        static public Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.Application m_app;


        public Result OnShutdown(UIControlledApplication application)
        {
            return Result.Succeeded;
        }

        public Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication application)
        {
            application.ControlledApplication.DocumentOpened += new EventHandler<DocumentOpenedEventArgs>(app_DocOpened);
            return Result.Succeeded;
        }

        public void app_DocOpened(object sender, DocumentOpenedEventArgs args)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("asd","asd");

            m_app.DocumentSynchronizingWithCentral += new EventHandler<DocumentSynchronizingWithCentralEventArgs>(m_app_DocumentSavingToCentral);
            m_app.DocumentSynchronizedWithCentral += new EventHandler<Autodesk.Revit.DB.Events.DocumentSynchronizedWithCentralEventArgs>(m_app_DocumentSavedToCentral);
        }

        void m_app_DocumentSavingToCentral(object sender, Autodesk.Revit.DB.Events.DocumentSynchronizingWithCentralEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("sync", "sync");
        }

        void m_app_DocumentSavedToCentral(object sender, Autodesk.Revit.DB.Events.DocumentSynchronizedWithCentralEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Doone", "Done");
        }
    }
```

this worked....  Thanks largely in part to the SDK sample project EventsMonitor

```
namespace RevitModelHealth
{
    public class checkHealth : IExternalApplication
    {


        public Result OnShutdown(UIControlledApplication application)
        {
            return Result.Succeeded;
        }

        public Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication application)
        {
            application.ControlledApplication.DocumentSynchronizingWithCentral += new EventHandler<DocumentSynchronizingWithCentralEventArgs>(app_syncStart);
            application.ControlledApplication.DocumentSynchronizedWithCentral += new EventHandler<DocumentSynchronizedWithCentralEventArgs>(app_syncOver);
            return Result.Succeeded;
        }

        public void app_syncStart(object o ,DocumentSynchronizingWithCentralEventArgs args)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("","Stasrting");
        }

        public void app_syncOver(object o,DocumentSynchronizedWithCentralEventArgs args)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("", "Over");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
application.ControlledApplication.DocumentSynchronizingWithCentral += new EventHandler<DocumentSynchronizingWithCentralEventArgs>(m_app_DocumentSavingToCentral)
```

in your OnStartup() method.

The call is failing because instance member m_app is initialized to null.

The [UIApplication.ControlledApplication](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2018.1/35859972-2407-3910-cb07-bbb337e307e6.htm) object that raises the [DocumentSynchronizingWithCentralEventArgs](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2018.1/20644173-bd8c-3598-4ac1-4c874679f8e8.htm) is being accessible from the parameter to OnStartup.

Comment: Thank You.  But the event is not in the UIControlledApplication space, but in the ApplicationServices.Application space. I can register a "DocumentOpened" event and from that function, create the new event handler without exceptions, however, the event does not fire whwn I synchronize.  I will update code to illustrate...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 public void app_DocOpened(object sender, DocumentOpenedEventArgs args)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("asd","asd");

        Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.Application m_app = args.Document.Application;

        m_app.DocumentSynchronizingWithCentral += new EventHandler<DocumentSynchronizingWithCentralEventArgs>(m_app_DocumentSavingToCentral);
        m_app.DocumentSynchronizedWithCentral += new EventHandler<Autodesk.Revit.DB.Events.DocumentSynchronizedWithCentralEventArgs>(m_app_DocumentSavedToCentral);
    }
```